# How do you Update a null ExtendedDetail in an Tridion audience manager contact?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have some code which works with Contacts via the Tridion.AudienceManagement.API. When working with existing contacts, some of them will have different `ExtendedDetail`s than others. I'm having trouble when I want to populate a value which doesn't already have a value

```
var extendedDetail = contact.ExtendedDetails[fieldName];
if (extendedDetail == null)
{
  // What do I do here?
}
```

The problem is that when a given ExtendedDetail is null, I have no way to set its value. The code examples in the documentation don't cover this example, and the API documentation doesn't explain what a null ExtendedDetail means, let alone how to create one, and populate it appropriately.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that extendedDetail could ever be null - I'd have expected there to always be an ExtendedDetail object, even if it had no value - reflecting the fact that AM Contacts share the same extended detail fields even if they're not all used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get/set the values of ExtendedDetails using `.Value`.

```cs
var extendedDetail = contact.ExtendedDetails[fieldName].Value;
if (extendedDetail == null)
{
  contact.ExtendedDetails[fieldName].Value = "VALUE"
}
```

For your reference please take a look at the documentation "Audience Manager .NET API" (chm) and check the "ExtendedDetail" class for some examples.

UPDATE: I have not seen a scenario when the ExtendedDetails will be null. I tested with the following bare minimum data to create a Contact and then get the extended data details. When you are creating a contact you need to have `IDENTIFICATION_KEY` and `IDENTIFICATION_SOURCE` which are mandatory and part of `ExtendedDetails`, so you should not run into this scenario ever.

```cs
//Create a Contact with basic data..
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.EmailAddress = "abc@123.com";
contact.SubscriptionStatus = SubscriptionStatus.Subscribed;
contact.ExtendedDetails["IDENTIFICATION_KEY"].Value = "abc@123.com";
contact.ExtendedDetails["IDENTIFICATION_SOURCE"].Value = "Website";
contact.Save();


// UPDATE the User Profile ..
ContactId = new string [] { "abc@123.com", "Website" };
Contact contact = Contact.GetFromContactIdentificatonKeys(ContactId);
contact.ExtendedDetails["NAME"].Value = "NAME";
```

Could you post the code on how you're creating a Contact ?

Comment: How should I do that if contact.ExtendedDetails[fieldName] is null? Where will I find it's Value property?

Comment: We are using to create new user as well and I don't see the extendeddetail[fieldname] as null. Strange, will check it trow again.

Comment: Thanks Ram. This is about updating an existing Contact. With new ones there's no problem

Comment: Dom, I checked it and I never see when the Extended Details will be null even if you create with bare minimum data of the Contact. I am updating the answer with what I have test.

Comment: The new contact scenario works fine. This is about an existing contact where we want to update a field that was previously missing. We're searching for the contacts based on their email address, which is the identification key. We get a Contact from the API, but then we see these problems. Since first encountering these problems, I have discovered that the Contacts obtained this way are 'read only' and you have to instantiate a new contact object to get a writeable one. I haven't yet checked to see if this correlates with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your Extended Detail is null, it's probably because you're trying to specify a field that isn't actually there. Maybe you misspelled it or your database table hasn't been updated, or recent changes that you made to the database have not been picked up yet (the Extended Details collection is heavily cached for obvious reasons).

In short, if the Extended Detail is defined in the database it will be available in that collection -- so it won't be null.